# DNM USD-6 fork service intervals and procedures

Tags: maintenance, fork

What are the good service intervals for the DNM USD-6 fork? How to understand that it should be maintained first? What are the recommended procedures for this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the website! Typically, it is the manufacturer's recommendations that apply for the procedures, as all forks are different inside and require different specific tools. The maintenance should be *preventive*, meaning it is done before the fork shows any signs of degradation. A typical service interval is 50 hours of operation at least, but it is up for the manufacturer to define, it can be more, or less.

Comment: Hi Grigory! I am not so sure about the 50 hours, because this is an inverted fork (USD probably means "upside-down"). The manufacturer's manual is very short and has no maintenance suggestions: https://www.dnmshock.com/upload_files/products/10/usd-6.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](https://www.dnmshock.com/upload_files/products/10/usd-6.pdf) linked in the comments states that the fork should be serviced every 10 months, every year or every two years, depending on its usage conditions, at an authorized shop.

[image: Table from manual]

The service intervals are expressed in terms of months of owning rather than in riding hours. However, the suggested maintenance intervals lie in the expected order of magnitude for values for how often people service their forks in the real world (from twice a year to once in two years, depending on the usage).

Comment: Thank you, this is informative.    Just in case if anyone knows how to replace the oil without the "authorized DNM repair shop", please share the experience.

Comment: There is a bit of discussion on the internet around DNM suspension products on the MTB forums. A few people mention that internals of certain DNM forks are identical to some other branded forks, which might help if those other forks do have service guides published. Otherwise, with absence of official support materials, all you have is experimentation and your mechanical skills. Where to obtain wear and tear items (seals etc.) for it is also a question. That fork is cheap however, so the worst that can happen is you lose its money's worth, and you have to be very rough to achieve that.